# Creating readable models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have just started with Rails and coming from a .net background I find the model inheriting from ActiveRecord is hard to understand, since the don't contain the corresponding attributes for the model. I cannot imagine a new developer exposed to a large code where the models only contains references to other models and business logic.

From my point of view the DataMapper model is much easier to grasp but since ActiveRecord is the defacto standard it feels weird to change the ORM just for this little problem.

*DataMapper*

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial    # An auto-increment integer key
  property :title,      String    # A varchar type string, for short strings
  property :body,       Text      # A text block, for longer string data.
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end
```

*ActiveRecord*

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 end
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue and that people get used to the models without attributes, or how does experienced rails user handle this?

I don't think using the database manager or looking at loads of migrations scripts to find the attributes is an option?

Specifying **attr_accessible** will make the model more readable but I'm not sure if it's a proper solution for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the annotate_models plugin on github. It will insert a commented schema for each model in a comment block. It can be installed to run when migrate is.

Comment: annotate_models is nice and I will use it for my models. Even if I like DataMapper better, I'll stick to ActiveRecord since it's the default.

Comment: I agree with grifaton in the answer below. Your db/schema.rb file is a de facto place to look for this information.

Every project I've seen using annotate_models has out of date comments. People forget to run the task and/or get sick of the noise at the top of the model files.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to "look at loads of migration scripts to find the attributes" - they're all defined in one place in db/schema.rb.

Answer (score 2):

A few tips:

- Load up the Rails console and enter
  `Post.column_names` for a quick
  reminder of the attribute names.
  `Post.columns` gives you the column
  objects, which shows the datatypes
- db/schema.rb contains all the
  migration code in one place, so you
  can easily see all the column
  definitions.
- If you are using a
  decent editor/IDE there should be a way to
  allowing you to jump from the model file
  to the migration file. (e.g. Emacs
  with ROR or Rinari)